# Requirement of Convexity to Linearize the Absolute Value Minimization Problem

Tags: convex-optimization, linear-programming

Let us consider that we have to minimize $\sum_{i=1}^{n} c_i \lvert x_i \rvert$ such that $\mathbf{Ax} \geq \mathbf{b}$ where $\mathbf{A} \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$ and $m<n$.

Clearly, it is a convex problem if $c_i$'s are all positive.

The problem can be linearized by using the fact that $\lvert x_i\rvert \leq z_i$. So, we put this as constraints and rewrite the objective function as $\sum_{i=1}^{n} c_i z_i$.

But, I am not able to realize where we need the fact that $c_i$'s are positive if we are trying to solve the following optimization problem:

\begin{eqnarray*}
& \min_{\mathbf{x},\mathbf{z} \in \mathbb{R}^n} & \sum_{i=1}^{n} c_i z_i\\
& \text{s.t.} & \mathbf{Ax} \geq \mathbf{b}\\
& & x_i \leq z_i \text{ and } -x_i \leq z_i, \forall i= 1, \dots,n.
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: Suppose $c_1 <0$ then you could make the cost be as small as you want by choosing sufficiently large $z_1$.

Comment: We can solve the reformulated problem for any $c_i$, but only for $c_i\geq 0$ it is equivalent to the original problem with absolute values.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I can see now what I was missing out previously.